Example 1.1 Nonlinear Control Khalil
$f( x) =\begin{bmatrix}
-x_{1} \ +x_{1} x_{2}\\
x_{2} \ -x_{1} x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$
is continuously differentiable on $R^2$. Hence, it is locally Lipschitz on $R^2$. It is not globally Lipschitz since $\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}$ and $\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}$ are not uniformly bounded on $R^2$. On any compact subset of $R^2$, f in Lipschitz. Suppose we are interested in calculating a Lipschitz constant over the set $W=\{|x_{1} \leq a,|x_{2} |\leq a\}$
$
 \begin{array}{l}
|f_{1}( x) -f_{1}( y) |\leq |x_{1} -y_{1} |+|x_{1} x_{2} -y_{1} y_{2} |\\
|f_{2}( x) -f_{2}( y) |\leq |x_{2} -y_{2} |+|x_{1} x_{2} -y_{1} y_{2} |
\end{array}$
Using inequalities
(1)
$|x_{1} x_{2} -y_{1} y_{2} |\ =\ |x_{1}( x_{2} -y_{2}) +y_{2}( x_{1} -y_{1}) |\leq a|x_{2} -y_{2} |+a|x_{1} -y_{1} |$
(2)
$|x_{1} -y_{1} ||x_{2} -y_{2} |\ \leq \frac{1}{2} |x_{1} -y_{1} |^{2} +\frac{1}{2} |x_{2} -y_{2} |^{2}$
Somehow we obtain
(3)
$||f( x) -f( y) ||^{2} =|f_{1}( x) -f_{1}( y) |^{2} +|f_{2}( x) -f( y) |^{2} \leq ( 1+2a)^{2} ||x-y||^{2}$
Therefore, f is Lipschitz on W with Lipschitz constant $L=1+2a$
Questions :
1.Inequality (2), where does this come from? And how is it implemented into equation (3)?
2. How is (3) formed from the preceeding equations?

For the first one use concavity of $\ln$

Then use all the previous result in their order of appearance for the last inequality

For the second inequality, you should already know that $\ln$ is concave, hence for $a,b>0$, you have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\ln(a) + \ln(b)}{2} & \leqslant & \ln \left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right)\\ 
&\iff & \\
\ln(ab) & \leqslant & \ln \left( \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\right)\\ 
&\iff & \\
ab & \leqslant & \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4}\\ 
&\iff & \\
\frac{ab}{2} & \leqslant & \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}\\ 
&\iff & \\
ab & \leqslant & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}
\end{eqnarray}$$
Replacing $a$ by $|x_1 - y_1|$ and $b$ by $|x_2-y_2|$ we get the result (of course it is obvious if $a$ or $b$ is zero).
Then for the third, just combine all results:
$$\begin{align*}
\|f(x) - f(y)\|_2^2 &= |f_1(x) -f_1(y)|^2 + |f_2(x) -f_2(y)|^2 \\
&\leqslant (|x_{1} -y_{1}| + |x_{1}x_{2} -y_{1}y_{2}|)^2 + (|x_{2} -y_{2}| + |x_{1}x_{2} -y_{1}y_{2}|)^2 \\
&\leqslant ((1+a)|x_{1} -y_{1}| + a|x_{2} -y_{2}|)^2 + ((1+a)|x_{2} -y_{2}| + a|x_{1}-y_{1}|)^2 \\
&= ((1+a)^2 + a^2) (|x_{1} -y_{1}|^2 + |x_{2} -y_{2}|^2) + 4a(a+1) |x_{1} -y_{1}||x_{2} -y_{2}|\\
&\leqslant ((1+a)^2 + a^2) (|x_{1} -y_{1}|^2 + |x_{2} -y_{2}|^2) + 2a(a+1) (|x_{1} -y_{1}|^2+|x_{2} -y_{2}|^2)\\
&=((1+a)^2 +a^2 + 2a(a+1)) \|x-y\|^2 \\
&= (1+a + a )^2 \|x-y\|^2 \\ 
&= (1+2a)^2 \|x-y\|^2
\end{align*}$$
Which gives you the end result.
